# ConcurrentModificationException and no idea why?

Tags: java, set, concurrentmodification

I m trying to loop a group of people and for every person i get the friends. Then loop through the friends and for every friend  get his friends and call a method called groupPeople(). But there i m getting  ConcurrentModificationException. Any idea why ?

```
for (User user : this.groupA) {
            Set<User> listofFriends = user.getFriends();
             Iterator<User> iterator = listofFriends.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    User setElement = iterator.next();
                    Set<User> listofFriends2 = setElement.getFriends();
                    groupPeople(listofFriends2,10);
                }
        }
private void groupPeople(Set<User> group,int number) {
        for (User user : group) {
            int y = 0;
            while(y<number){
                user.addFriend(socialNetwork.getPeopleInNetwork().get(++counter));
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
  at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:922)
  at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956)
```

Comment: What is exactly the stacktrace and Which line dors it concern?

Comment: in the line  User setElement = iterator.next();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:922)
 at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956)

Comment: Post your groupPeople() method.

Comment: i edited my question now

Comment: It looks like when you do user.addFriend() in groupPeople(), the original listofFriends is getting altered. The iterator was obtained from listofFriends in the beginning and listofFriends is altered afterwards, which may be causing ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: what could i do to avoid that ?

Comment: One way is to use the same iterator that was obtained in the beginning to modify the collection afterwards. For ex: java.util.ListIterator that has methods to add elements. Since you're using a Set, ListIterator cannot be used. Another way is to use a fail-safe iterator such as one returned by java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet.

Comment: Check [what-is-difference-between-fail-fast-and-fail-safe-iterations-in-java](http://www.somanyword.com/2014/01/what-is-difference-between-fail-fast-and-fail-safe-iterations-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are altering the `Set<User> listofFriends` in one of these methods e.g. `groupPeople`

This could be because a User is friend of themselves, or `listOfFriends2` is the same Set, or something else you are doing in the method you call.

I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to find the problem.

Comment: @AkinDönmez You don't show where in your code you are getting the error which is much more interesting.  The basic problem is you can't be modifying a HashMap or HashSet while you are iterating over it.  Either you need to take a copy of the things you want to change, take a copy of the keys, or use a collection which supports concurrent access such as a ConcurrentHashMap